# What's the need for event masks in X11?

Tags: c, graphics, x11

hey i'm bit confused on the concept of event masks in X11, i've seen many definition of the concept online which seems different from one another, this is the manual definition:

> Clients select event reporting of most events relative to a window. To do this, pass an event mask to an Xlib event-handling function that takes an event_mask argument. The bits of the event mask are defined in X11/X.h. Each bit in the event mask maps to an event mask name, which describes the event or events you want the X server to return to a client application.

[link](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/mask.html) 
What i understood from this definition is that event masks are a ways to report an event to the client however in this other definition :

> The event mask defines which events the client is interested in for this InputOutput or InputOnly window (or, for some event types, inferiors of this window). The event mask is the bitwise inclusive OR of zero or more of the valid event mask bits. You can specify that no maskable events are reported by setting NoEventMask (default).

however this other definition says it's a way to chose whether to define that event in input and output or input only, [link](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/attributes/event-and-do-not-propagate.html)

the 2 definitions seems deferent and confusing, so what are exactly event masks in X11 and why we need them ?

PS: i didn't find a similar question in SO.

Comment: What you mention in a second definition is a property of a window. The property is called a "class" in a X11 terms. You set this property when you create a window. It has nothing to do with events that you interested in. Namely, it is a different `define`, or constant, as you may see in the links you had posted.

Answer (score 1):

The two definitions are both valid and describe the same functionality in the X11 ecosystem. When you instantiate an X11 window, if it supports input from the user (i.e. it is either an `InputOnly` or an `InputOutput` window), then the X server can send events to your application based on the input received by the window. These events describe things such as which key was pressed on the keyboard, which mouse button was pressed, etc.

However, you may not be interested in all the input events that may arise during the lifetime of your window. For example, you may only want to respond to keyboard events and not care about mouse events. You need to signal to the X server that you are only interested in a given set of events, and you use a bitmask for this. The following gives an example of how you may select only keyboard events for a given window.

```c
// We are only interested in keyboard events
long event_mask = KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask | KeymapStateMask;
// Set the input mask for our window on the current display
XSelectInput(display, window, event_mask);
```